# API AJAX Get Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to make an API `GET` request with ajax. I have a jquery function take an api key value from the 1st input field  and then display a concatenate result on input field #2 `url + api key`. I need to make the get request to the value displayed in the 2nd input field. How can I accomplish this get request? The target server is setup to allow for cross-domain scripting [SITE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/concatenate/)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {

  /** get the inputs we might need */
  var $result = $('#result');
  var $input = $('#input');

  $result.data('url', $result.val());
  var timer;

  /** function to submit data to the server and
      update the result input on success */
  function submitForm( input, newValue) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/concatenate/index.php",
      data: {input:input},
      success: function (data) {
        $result.val(newValue);
      }
    });
  };

  /** on key up, fill #result with the url + input */
  $input.bind('keyup', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var inp = $this.val();
    var url = $result.data('url');
    var newValue = url + inp + '/';

    if(timer) { clearTimeout(timer); }
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
      submitForm(inp, newValue) ;
    }, 40);
    return false;
  });

});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Enter a word:</h1>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
API Key: <input type="text" id="input" name="input"></br>
Concatenated Url + API: <input type="text" style="width:200px;" id="result" name="result" value="http//www.example.com/"></br>
</form>
```

Comment: if the url is a different domain than the domain the script is running on, then it won't work unless the target server is setup to allow for cross-domain scripting (by default, servers are not setup as such). This is cross-site scripting (read up on same domain origin policy)

Comment: @CrayonViolent The target server is setup to allow for cross-domain scripting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's probably lots of other ways to do this, but the first idea that popped in my head is to create the concatenated url in the `submitForm`. The reasoning is that by the time the timeout has been reached and its ready to make the ajax call, you'd want to grab whatever was in the `input` field at that exact moment to ensure you have the most "up-to-date" values (as much as possible). So perhaps something like this:

```
// Note: I've ditched the parameters because they are no longer needed
// We're getting the values that the parameters contained in this function
function submitForm() {
  var inp = $("#input").val();
  var url = $("#result").data('url');
  var concatenatedUrl = url + inp + '/';

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: concatenatedUrl,
    data: {input:input},
    success: function (data) {
      $result.val(newValue);
    }
  });
}
```

Hope that helps. Please let me know whether I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: I am trying to do a `GET` with `url + apikey` and display result back

Comment: @techAddict82 Sorry forgot that. Same thing though, you just change `type` to "GET". What part are you having trouble with exactly?

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks!